# SSRS Report Issue - The Visibility.Hidden expression for the tablix has an incorrect number of parameters for the function RowNumber

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

We have a single page SSRS report that I am attempting to turn into a multi-page report that returns several records. Currently there is no tablix / matrix grouping in the report, which I am understanding is needed in order to be able to utilize the 'next' function to return more records.

I very simply added a list to my report and copied and pasted the fields into the list so that there is a grouping. However, I am now receiving and error - "The Visibility.Hidden expression for the tablix has an incorrect number of parameters for the function RowNumber".

I do a fair bit of **simple** SSRS reports, but this one is beyond me and I'm not entirely sure where to start diagnosing or what information I need to provide.

Thank you, please let me know if I need to provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there seems to be an expression in the "Visibility" property of a component, and in that expression there is a "RowNumber(enter parameters here)" function, and it has the incorrect number of parameters. Note that "Visibility" can also be called "Hidden" when designing your report.

[image: Visibility&Hidden property]

If you have problems locating that expression, you can open your RDL file in Notepad and look for the words Visibility and RowNumber. Here's a snippet of what it could look like in your RDL file:

```
<Visibility>
  <Hidden>=RowNumber()</Hidden>
</Visibility>
```